# Was E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial shot in 1.85 or 2.35?

Tags: film-techniques, et-the-extra-terrestrial

I can see that the "E.T." movie is sold in 1.85 and 2.35 formats:

- http://www.amazon.fr/E-T-lExtra-Terrestre-Peluche-Dee-Wallace/dp/B008JELMU6/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top
- http://www.amazon.fr/E-T-lExtra-Terrestre-Combo-Blu-ray-DVD/dp/B0087OYKM0/ref=cm_cr_pr_orig_subj

I also know that on DVD boxes there is a mention that tells, near the used ratio on the back of the box, if it respects the original movie format. On one of the box I have (DVD), it's writen: "1,85:1 Anamorphic Widescreen". So I suppose that 1,85 is not the native format but a cropped one.

Could you tell me what is the cinema displayed ratio in France at the time it was projected?
Could you tell me what is the original movie ratio this movie was recorded?
- And best of all, if you could show a little scan of the mention on a DVD or BR box that confirms it.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Blu-Ray review](http://www.blu-ray.com/movies/ET-The-Extra-Terrestrial-Blu-ray/7850/) on Blu-Ray.com (which is an **outstanding** website for in-depth reviews of every aspect of a DVD/Blu-Ray release), the original presentation was 1.85:1

Comment: What will happen if the original presentation was 1.85:1 and the BR claims to be in 2.35 (http://www.amazon.fr/E-T-lExtra-Terrestre-Peluche-Dee-Wallace/dp/B008JELMU6/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top) ?